# Static methods on generic classes?

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

Okay, this is the case:

I got a generic base-class which I need to initialize with some static values. These values have nothing to do with the kind of types my generic baseclass is loaded with.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
GenericBaseclass.Initialize(AssociatedObject);
```

while also having a class doing like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : GenericBaseclass<int>
{
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I could make a non-generic baseclass and put the static method there, but I don't like that "hack" :)

Comment: Aside from a non-generic base class being the only way to do it as has already been pointed out, I just want to add that doing so is not a 'hack' but is in fact the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the values have nothing to do with the type of the generic base class, then they shouldn't be in the generic base class. They should either be in a completely separate class, or in a non-generic base class of the generic class.

Bear in mind that for static variables, you get a different static variable per type argument combination:

```
using System;

public class GenericType<TFirst, TSecond>
{
    // Never use a public mutable field normally, of course.
    public static string Foo;
}

public class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        // Assign to different combination
        GenericType<string,int>.Foo = "string,int";
        GenericType<int,Guid>.Foo = "int,Guid";
        GenericType<int,int>.Foo = "int,int";
        GenericType<string,string>.Foo = "string,string";


        // Verify that they really are different variables
        Console.WriteLine(GenericType<string,int>.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(GenericType<int,Guid>.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(GenericType<int,int>.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(GenericType<string,string>.Foo);

    }
}
```

It sounds like you don't *really* want a different static variable per `T` of your generic base class - so you can't have it *in* your generic base class.

Comment: "Should" as in "best practice" or "should" as in "the only way to accomplish the desired behavior" ? :)

Comment: If you only want one static variable despite different type arguments being provided, it's "the only way to accomplish the desired behavior".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.. I should've done that my self, sorry about that. Makes perfect sense though :) - Now, go to bed Mr. Know-it-all :P

Answer (score 10):

That's exactly what you have to do.  When you have a type parameter, each different instantiation of the type is a *separate* type.  This leads to separate static variables.

The only workaround is to have a base class that the generic class derives from.